# How to pass form data using POST method and JS submit()?

Tags: javascript, html

How to pass form data using POST method and JS submit() ?

I would like not to use AJAX.

I can achieve that by using JS and GET method, but my goal now is to use JS (probably with submit() ) and POST method.

Please give a simple working example.

Thank you!

Edited: Sorry, I will be more specific.
Here is a simple code I have:

```
<form name=\"myform\" action=\"\">
  Search: <input type='text' name='query' />
  <a href=\"javascript: submitform()\">Search</a>
</form>

 <script type=\"text/javascript\">
 function submitform() {   document.myform.submit(); }
 </script>
```

When I insert "word" into the input field and press Search, the URL becomes "../index.php?query=word" and that means that form data is passed like GET method.

And my goal is to remove any form data from URL and pass it like with POST method.

Edited: ohh.. I just added method=post and no form data in the URL anymore :)

Comment: Can you please show us your current HTML/JS ... not really sure why this is tagged PHP ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just have a form and submit it.

```
form = document.forms[0] //assuming only form.
form.submit();
```

---

### EDIT: OP has clarified question

Specify a `method` attribute on your form.

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="POST">
```

It will cause the form to be submitted as a POST.

Answer (score 3):

Set the form's `method` attribute to POST:

```
<form method="post">
```

And then submit the form via JavaScript using `<formelement>.submit()`

Comment: something like `document.getElementById('theForm').submit()`

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned already, you can use a form.  I find it useful to have a function which creates a form on-the-fly and submits it - that way you don't need to clutter your markup with forms until they're needed by your JS.

```
function PostObjectToUri(uri, obj) {
    "use strict";

    var json, form, input;

    json = JSON.stringify(obj);

    form = document.createElement("form");
    form.method = "post";
    form.action = uri;
    input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("name", "json");
    input.setAttribute("value", json);
    form.appendChild(input);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
};
```

Obviously that example JSON-serializes an object into a string and sets it on a single input, but you could adapt it to do whatever you need.

**EDIT**: I'm not actually sure whether you even need to append to the DOM before submitting - can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery AJAX post is best way to do it. See below example code.

```
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: 'data.php',
   data: $('form').serialize(),
   success: function(response) {
      $('#DisplayDiv').html(response);
   }
});
```